# Smallest dimensional irreps of semi-simple Lie algebras

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-algebras

I'm wondering if there is a reference that lists the first couple smallest dimensional irreducible representations of each semi-simple Lie algebra.  I know these can be found using the Weyl dimension formula, but it would be handy if this is already written down somewhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but http://www-math.univ-poitiers.fr/~maavl/LiE/form.html should answer any *specific* question (if you experiment a bit; "Dimension of a module" is your friend).